# find the position of element in array?

Tags: java, algorithm

I've `array of N integers` in not-decreasing order. Need to find any specific element in array, if found then return the position of that array otherwise returns `-1`

```
public static int find(int[] v, int bb) {
    int N = v.length;
    if (N == 0) {
        return -1;
    }
    int l = 0;
    int r = N - 1;
    while (l < r) {
        int m = (l + r) / 2;
        if (v[m] > bb) {
            r = m - 1;
        } else {
            l = m;
        }
    }
    if (v[l] == bb) {
        return l;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

there's one bug I need to find out, which is about that this will not work for some inputs.  I gave up.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: By "in not-decreasing order", do you mean that it's NOT in decreasing order, or do you mean that it's in increasing order, but with possible duplicate elements?  Also, what inputs doesn't it work for?

Comment: right, its not in decreasing order. and need to find out and fix for which it will not work

Comment: OK, if you don't know that it's in increasing order, you shouldn't be trying to use a binary search.  You could either check each element individually in any order, or you could sort the array first and then use a binary search.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to locate the index of the first **specific** numerical element within the array then you can do something like this:

```
public static int find(int[] v, int bb) {
    int found = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < v.length; i++) {
        if (v[i] == bb) {
            found = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    return found;
}
```

If there are multiple values in the array that are the same as `bb` then the method above will only provide the first one found. If you want to return the index values for **all** values of `bb` found in the array then you would want to return an array of index values, for example:

```
public static int[] find(int[] v, int bb) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    int found = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < v.length; i++) {
        if (v[i] == bb) {
            found = i;
            list.add(found);
        }
    }
    if (found == -1) { 
        list.add(found); 
    }
    return list.stream().mapToInt(d -> d).toArray();
}
```

The **List Interface** is used in the above example because it can grow dynamically since we have no idea how many values of `bb` are actually going to be contained within the Array. The List is converted to an **int[]** array before it is returned.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think you should name your variables with a proper name, and not just with a single characters, it'll make your code easier to understand.

Second, you are using a binary serach algorithm for increasing ordered arrays, if you want that code to work correctly you have to use an increasing ordered array. Here you have a binary search method that should work with increasing ordered arrays:

```
public static int binarySeacrh(int [] list, int numSearched) {
    
    boolean found = false;
    int start = 0;
    int end = list.length - 1;
    int pos = -1;

    while(start <= end && !found){
        int middle=((start + end) / 2);
        if (numSearched == list[middle]){
            found = true;
            pos = middle;
        } 
        else if (list[middle] < numSearched){
            start = middle + 1;
        }else{
            end = middle - 1;
        }
    }
    
    return pos;
}
```

If you want to search for the position in a unordered array, you must use another type of serach algorithm or order the array first.

Comment: This is not true. Binary search works as long as the set is sorted, doesn't matter if it's increasingly or decreasingly sorted.

Comment: Yes, but the algorithm should have some changes in it, the binary search used by him/her only works with increasing ordered array. If you want to search in a decreasing ordered array you should change the if / else block a bit, no?

Comment: The binary search algorithm works for decreasingly and increasingly sorted sets. You should write it for either cases. The fact that the array is in decreasingly order shouldn't prevent us from writing the proper generic algorithm.